# Update ListView from IntentService

Tags: android, multithreading, intentservice

I have an IntentService which creates an Overlay with the help of a WindowManager. In the WindowManager I add a View which contains a ListView. Now I want to add a new Item to the ListView in the onHandleIntent Method but if I call

```
data.add("String");
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

the system throws an error

```
Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: Have a look at [content providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html). They would help you.

Comment: create a handler in onStart, then post on this handler a message to update the view, if I understand correctly what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

The screen may only be updated by the UI thread.  A service cannot guarantee that it is running in the UI thread.  Therefor a service may not update the screen directly.

The solution is to send a message to the UI thread.  There are many ways to do this.  Here is one:

In onCreate() for the Activity attached to the screen create a message handler:

```
  mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message inputMessage) {
       Update the UI here using data passed in the message.
    }
  }
```

Make mHandler available to the service (possibly via the intent used in StartService().

In the service send the a message to the handler:

```
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(...);
      ... add info to msg as necessary
    msg.sendToTarget();
```

These pages may help with the details:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

and

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by letting the Activity that holds the ListView to do the update. [Activity.runOnUiThread()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) should do the job =]

Comment: I don't see where I have an Activity there... I only have the IntentService with the Overlay